# Angular2: Error for "start": "tsc && concurrently..."

Tags: angular, npm

In package.json I have:

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\"",
   ... 
}
```

when I run it by "npm start" I get the error:

> npm ERR! Failed at the Angular2Try@1.0.0 start script 'tsc &&
>   concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite"'. 
>   npm ERR! Make sure you
>   have the latest version of node.js and npm installed. 
>   npm ERR! If you
>   do, this is most likely a problem with the Angular2Try package
>   npm ERR! not with npm itself.

I have the latest versions of nodejs (v7.5.0) and npm (v4.1.2), so I don't think this is the issue.

By the way, when I change it to:

```
"start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\"",
```

it works :)

Answer (score 0):

This may not answer your question exactly but I wanted to share what I wrote in my package.json scripts file for a couple of angular 2 apps and conjecture on your resolution - 
* My conclusion is to suggest **leaving out "npm run" from your scripts.start string**

It would look like **"tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",**

My app is using the default scripts from the [angular Quickstart](https://github.com/angular/quickstart) files

In the correct directory I type "npm start" into my console

The difference the scripts.start line in mine is there's no "npm run" keyword
Here's what my package.json shows:

```
    "scripts" {
         "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
```

On another project I followed some guide to build the package.json file.  I type "npm run app" to utilize the scripts

and I ended up with this code in scripts.start:

```
    "scripts" {
         "tsc": "tsc",
         "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
         "lite": "lite-server",
         "app": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
```

Answer (score 0):

I also got this to work:

```
{
  "name": "ng2-start",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings",
    "postinstall": "typing install"
  },
```